# Application mixing QWidget and QML for embedded linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

I wrote an application mixing some QWidget and QML code with Qt 5.5.1. 
I'm now trying to deploy it for my linux target. (linux kernel on imx6)
No error occurred during the cross-compilation.

But I got some issue when I execute it on the target.
Depending on the platform I got different error : 
EGLFS :   "EGLFS: OpenGL windows cannot be mixed with others."

LinuxFB : "This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat"

As far as I understood, EGLFS cannot display QWidget and QML at the same time and linuxFB cannot display QML using QtQuick 2.4.

I'm planning to install X.org on the target in order to display correctly my application. But I think it's a bit too "heavy" for a single application.

Do you know any other way to display correctly my application?